# Entity Framework Core 5.0 scaffolding issue in DB first

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, db-first

I'm trying to scaffold a DB model using DB first with Scaffold-DbContext.
The error I get is: `The types of the properties specified for the foreign key {'PARTNER_GROUP'} on entity type 'PARTNER' do not match the types of the properties in the principal key {'ID'} on entity type 'STATUS'.`

The only relation of STATUS table with PARTNER table is through some other relationships, and the only thing that smells with PARTNER_GROUP(nullable) field is that there is a PARTNER_ID(not null) primary key in the PARTNER table which has different nullability.

Comment: Read the error message: status.id and partner.partner_group are not the same type

Comment: There's no way to tell unless you post the table DDL for the tables that generate the scaffolding error.

Comment: @ErikEJ status.id and partner.partner_group are completely unrelated id values. It can only be that the status class holds a collection property which holds a property that points to the partner entity.